# What replaces text.latex.unicode?

Tags: python, matplotlib, unicode

In my `matplotlibrc`, I'm using the [`text.latex.unicode`](https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html#usetex-with-unicode) rcparam, as (still) recommended by the documentation:

```
#text.latex.unicode : False # use "ucs" and "inputenc" LaTeX packages for handling
                            # unicode strings.

text.latex.unicode : True
```

But since Matplotlib 3.0, I am getting a MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:

```
/group_workspaces/cems2/fiduceo/Users/gholl/anaconda3/envs/FCDR37a/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:846: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The text.latex.unicode rcparam was deprecated in Matplotlib 2.2 and will be removed in 3.1.
  "2.2", name=key, obj_type="rcparam", addendum=addendum)
/group_workspaces/cems2/fiduceo/Users/gholl/anaconda3/envs/FCDR37a/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:846: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The text.latex.unicode rcparam was deprecated in Matplotlib 2.2 and will be removed in 3.1.
  "2.2", name=key, obj_type="rcparam", addendum=addendum)
```

What is the replacement for the deprecated `text.latex.unicode` rcparam?

Unfortunately, I can't seem to reach the [Matplotlib Tex Cookbook](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/UsingTex) at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [api change notes](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/api_changes.html#changes-regarding-the-text-latex-unicode-rcparam) tell us

> Changes regarding the `text.latex.unicode` rcParam
>   The rcParam now defaults to True and is deprecated (i.e., in future versions of Maplotlib, unicode input will always be supported).
>   Moreover, the underlying implementation now uses `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` instead of `\usepackage{ucs}\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`.

This essentially means that if you use matplotlib 2.2 or higher, you should just leave that parameter out completely.

This is also reflected in [the example of the current documentation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/tex_demo.html) where there is no such parameter used.

Also the [current version of the rc file](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#a-sample-matplotlibrc-file) does not even have this parameter in it.

Comment: But they haven't been removed from the rcsetup.py module...So they still show up in `rcParams` and throw warnings, even if those parameters are not explicitly set by the user.

Comment: `examples.directory` has the same issue.

Comment: @mrclary Yes, they are still there, but they shouldn't throw a warning. What exact issue do you face?

Comment: you are correct and I was mistaken. It turns out that I had a bug in my own code that was causing these warnings to be raised. I was setting an `rc_context` context manager using a dictionary of rc parameters that was derived from `rcParams`. `rcParams` still has both `text.latex.unicode` and `examples.directory`, but does _not_ raise a warning when initializing a context manager; however, a _dictionary_ with these items _does_ raise the warning.